# Fetch health information from smartwatch and transfer it to mobile phone via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, wear-os, wearables, redmi-device

I need to get the data like heart rate and blood oxygen level from smartwatch and send it to a mobile phone.

I researched and found out I could use the [Data Layer API](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/data-layer) to synch and send data between a wearable device and a phone. But this is only limited for Wear OS. The smartwatch I'm testing on is *Redmi Watch 2 Lite*. How do I fetch data from it and send it to the app I'm developing? I'm new to wearable development so I'd really appreciate it if you could provide any links or tutorials.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible or at least not easily doable. The Redmi Watch 2 Lite does not have publicly available API, therefore your only two options are to either contact Redmi and ask them for the API, or try and reverse engineer the workings of the watch. The reason that this is not going to be straightforward is because the watch uses custom BLE services/characteristics for their data, so you will need an app like nRF Connect to use connect to the watch and try to figure out the BLE API and data structure yourself.